# Concat arrays in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, concatenation

I build this array:

```
const array = [
  {
    title: 'something',
    list: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
  },
  {
    title: 'dog',
    list: ['aa']
  },
  {
    title: 'cat',
    list: ['aaa', 'b', 'cccc']
  },
  {
    title: 'apple',
    list: [],
  }
]
```

I would like an array containing all the values in the other arrays, so:

```
const res = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'aa', 'aaa', 'b', 'cccc']
```

I can I do that? I can use `concat` but how?

Comment: What specifically are you having an issue figuring out? It seems fairly straight-forward.

Comment: `array.reduce((result,item)=>result.concat(item.list),[])`

Comment: what is expected output

Comment: @MaheerAli The array shown in the question?

Comment: None of the answers mention it, but since you seem to be relatively new to JS, you could also just iterate and concat each object's `list` to an accumulator array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could reduce the array for flattening a property.

```js
const
    array = [{ title: 'something', list: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] }, { title: 'dog', list: ['aa'] }, { title: 'cat', list: ['aaa', 'b', 'cccc'] }, { title: 'apple', list: [] }],
    list = array.reduce((r, { list }) => [...r, ...list], []);

console.log(list);
```

Or take maybe upcoming [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap).

```js
const
    array = [{ title: 'something', list: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] }, { title: 'dog', list: ['aa'] }, { title: 'cat', list: ['aaa', 'b', 'cccc'] }, { title: 'apple', list: [] }],
    list = array.flatMap(({ list }) => list);

console.log(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `concat` and `reduce` together

```js
var a=[
  {
    title: 'something',
    list: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
  },
  {
    title: 'dog',
    list: ['aa']
  },
  {
    title: 'cat',
    list: ['aaa', 'b', 'cccc']
  },
  {
    title: 'apple',
    list: [],
  }
];
console.log(a.reduce((acc,e)=>acc.concat(e.list),[]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `concat` on empty array with `map` and spread syntax `...`.

```js
const array = [{"title":"something","list":["a","b","c","d"]},{"title":"dog","list":["aa"]},{"title":"cat","list":["aaa","b","cccc"]},{"title":"apple","list":[]}]

const res = [].concat(...array.map(({list}) => list))
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Forget `flatmap` and `reduce`. Keep things simple and easy to understand.

```
var res = []
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    res = res.concat(array[i]["list"])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using `reduce` and the `...`(spread operator) it is very simple to do.

```js
const array = [{
    title: 'something',
    list: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
  },
  {
    title: 'dog',
    list: ['aa']
  },
  {
    title: 'cat',
    list: ['aaa', 'b', 'cccc']
  },
  {
    title: 'apple',
    list: [],
  }
]

const result = array.reduce((accum, item) => {
  return [...accum, ...item.list]
}, [])

console.log(result);
```